# Php generate random and different numbers

Tags: php, random

I create this in php for generate random numbers

```
> <?php
> 
> $products=array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10");
> 
> for ($i=0;$i<count($products);$i++) {
> 
> $numbers=rand(0,count(products));
> 
> print "".$products[$numbers]."<br>";
> 
> } ?>
```

I try generate in bucle different numbers but always show me the same numbers 1212121212 and nothing more , how i can generate this string or array and for example finally show 2 3 4 1 5 6 7 9 8 10 , and if reload script other combination

Thank´s Regards !!!

Comment: `count(products)` shouldn't it be `count($products)`?

Comment: You could simply [`shuffle`](http://php.net/shuffle) the array.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the `$` in `count($products)`. As a result, the parser is treating it as the string `"products"`, which has a `count()` of 1. Therefore, the `rand()` function returns zero or one, which in your original array correspond to `"1"` and `"2"`.

Comment: Yes i solve that i put bad when i insert the post , but the problem continue , because many numbers repit all time and no able get different numbers and no repit , thank´s

Answer (score 1):

Try using [shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php),

```
$products=array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"); 
shuffle($products);
foreach($products as $v)
 echo $v;
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/Zg3reZ4P)